# Swift auto update?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just starting out learning Swift development... and while creating my first little stopwatch app I couldn't seem to get my variable to update within the string without assigning it again in the `startTimerr()` function.

If removed the reassignment of `timerLabel.text` to `"\(counter)"`, once ran the `UILabel` would not update. I'd just like to know the right way of doing this, and a push in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var counter = 0
    var timer: Timer!

    @IBOutlet weak var startBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        startBtn.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        startBtn.setTitleColor(.systemGray, for: .normal)
        startBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)

        stopBtn.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        stopBtn.setTitleColor( .systemGray, for: .normal)
        stopBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)

        resetBtn.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        resetBtn.setTitleColor(.systemGray, for: .normal)
        resetBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)

        timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        timerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }

    @objc func startTimerr() {
        counter = counter + 1
        timerLabel.text =  "\(counter)"
    }


    @IBAction func startTime(_ sender: Any) {
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(startTimerr), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    @IBAction func stopTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        counter = 0
        timerLabel.text =  "\(counter)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much the expected way to handle it with UIKit. When you create a string from the counter Int, that string is not in any way connected to the original Int. You need to explicitly tell UIKit to update the text label when the value changes.

You could try

```
    var counter = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        }
    }
```

and change

```
    @objc func startTimerr() {
        counter = counter + 1
    }
```

But it doesn't make much of a difference really.